# How to access electron.app.getPath()?

Tags: reactjs, electron, brave

Hi I'm making a custom component under `js/about`. How can I make `getPath()` available inside my component? Brave components seem to have access to it(via `const {app} = require('electron')`) without requiring remote module.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access it from your main process this will be enough.

```
const {app} = require('electron');
app.getPath('exe');
```

However if you need it from the renderer process test this out.

```
const {app} = require('electron').remote;
app.getPath('exe');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Even if it did I'd like it to be consistent with Brave's implementation -- that is no remote module.

Comment: what is "Brave's implementation"??

Comment: @DEDaniel, adredx may have been referring to the Brave browser.